# Receiving webhook from GitHub from C# Console App

Tags: c#, github, webhooks

I'd like to capture webhooks from GitHub (for various events, like commits, etc), from my C# console application. I figured I could "listen" to an endpoint and webhooks would be thrown there, but it seems that perhaps github is actually sending webhooks to endpoints that you need to setup and listen from.

If the latter is this case, then I suppose I'll need to setup a web server to capture the webhooks. If the former is the case, then I'm not finding in the docs how I can listen for webhooks from GitHub?

Comment: You found a solution or documentation regarding this issue ?

Comment: Not a copy/paste solution, but the goal is essentially as Dan Forbes said below, which is to implement your own web server to listen to these webhooks. Then configure GitHub to push them to your endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think you're on the right track vis-a-vis implementing a web server. So, my answer to your question is: you need to implement a web server to receive the webhook requests.

*Edit*

At the bottom of [this document](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md#example-webhook-receiver), you will find instructions on how to implement a very simple web server (in Ruby) to receive **GitLab** webhook requests. I know this isn't a turnkey solution for you, but hopefully it will help get you going.